# Why does a dictionary with tuple keys initiated with zip update all keys upon update of a single key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I just got got by a gotcha. This code acts as you would expect:

```
keys = range(8)

DICT={}
for k in keys:
    DICT[k] = []
print DICT
#returns
#{0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}

DICT[1].append('mkay')
print DICT
#returns
#{0: [], 1: ['mkay'], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}
```

But if I initialize the dictionary differently, the appending behavior is totally different:

```
DICT = dict(zip(keys,[[]]*len(keys)))
print DICT
#returns
#{0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}
```

So it looks the same. But it's not:

```
DICT[1].append('mkay')
print DICT
#returns
#{0: ['mkay'], 1: ['mkay'], 2: ['mkay'], 3: ['mkay'], 4: ['mkay'], 5: ['mkay'], 6: ['mkay'], 7: ['mkay']}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Thought I'd post this as well for anyone else who might get got by it.

Comment: Nothing mysterious. By multiplying `[[]]` with `len(keys)` you have created a list of lists that all of them point to same object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36452923/2201041 for an answer that made it more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every value in the dictionary refers to the same list, because of `[[]]*len(keys)`. That says "create a list, and copy the reference to it `len(keys)` times".

Comment: I see. So `len(keys)` pointers are going to the same list. I assumed it just made `len(keys)` different lists!